# how to stretch a UITextField on begin editng

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to increase the size of UITextField when editing begins, but just cant get the code to do it.

Comment: What is the code you have written so far ? That will help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gomathi is correct. Just to add to his answer if you want the textFIeld to expand when editing begins and shrink back again when editing ends and also want to animate it, you might wanna do something like this:

```
    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        textField.frame = CGRectMake(textField.frame.origin.x-20, textField.frame.origin.y, textField.frame.size.width+40, textField.frame.size.height);
    }];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        textField.frame = CGRectMake(textField.frame.origin.x+20, textField.frame.origin.y, textField.frame.size.width-40, textField.frame.size.height);
    }];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextFieldDelegate).

In `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`, set the new frame size to the textfield. Then call, `[textField setNeedsDisplay];`.